# extract any table to excel file using utl_file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to create A procedure to extract all data of any Table or view in the parameter of the program
using pl/sql
And thanks in advance.

Comment: See answer posted on AskTom: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9542084600346455496

Comment: Yes, and now: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

you could select the specified tables and views as a cursor from the systemables „all_tables“ and „all_views“ (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20305) - loop through them and write the data using utl_file to disk. Easiest way to get into excel would be an separated ascii-file or CSV (http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2011/09/create-csv-file-using-plsql.html). For xml or xls you will have to use an package - depending on your database version.
If its all for an one-time-export use the sql-developer.